# setjmp/longjmp and the state of open files

Tags: c, language-lawyer, file-descriptor, setjmp

The C standard says that

> All  accessible  objects  have  values,  and  all  other  components  of  the  abstract  machine<sup>218)</sup>
> have  state,  as  of  the  time  the longjmp function  was  called,  except  that  the  values  of
> objects  of  automatic  storage  duration  that  are  local  to  the  function  containing  the
> invocation  of  the  corresponding setjmp macro  that  do  not  have  volatile-qualified  type
> and have been changed between the setjmp invocation and longjmp call are
> indeterminate."
>
> 218) This includes, but is not limited to, the floating-point status flags **and the state of open files**.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

What is the goal of this requirement, and how do implementations deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "as of the time the **longjmp** function was called", not setjmp, so the requirement is simply to *not* save/restore too much state, which is easy. (I had to re-read this quite a few times to notice this...)